# Equivalent resistance in a circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrical-resistance

I have this circuit and I need to find an equivalent resistance. I am very confused by the shape of the circuit because it appears like a more complex problem than I think it should be.

Ultimately, I think this is simply a series of 3 resistors and the total resistance should be 3R. Is this correct or do the extra wires matter?
[image]

Comment: Hint: you can move everything around as long as you keep the topology the same. Try placing all points of the same voltage as $A$ at the top, and all points of the same voltage as $B$ at the bottom.

Comment: I gave wrong answer. I deleted it to avoid confusion. I agree it is R/3 now instead of R/2.

Comment: I suppose the first resistor has the same voltage as A and the third resistor has the same voltage as B but I don't understand how this shows it's parallel.

Answer (score 4):

the answer should be R/3, the resistances are in parallel. you need to modify the circuit a little bit.

Comment: Correct!  I had just drawn that parallel circuit when your answer popped up.

Comment: I really can't figure out how this can be rearranged into a parallel circuit. What's the first step?

Comment: @M123 I've uploaded a picture in gdrive: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B62aoMeV8pdHSmcwRnFxN1Uxc2s) . Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Req = 1/(1/R + 1/R + 1/R) = 1 /3/R = R/3

The point after two R is A, and the point between two R is B. So just flip those points to make a single point of A and B, respectively. Then, you will see that the resistances are all in parallel. Thus, the total equivalent resistance is R/3.

Comment: If you vote down this answer that means you don't understand it well.

Answer (score -5):

The extra wires absolutely do matter. There is a wire that shorts the first two resistors, meaning that there really is only one resistor in the circuit. So, the effective resistance is R.